# Swift 4: getter and setter directly in a struct or class

Tags: swift

I am trying to come up with a way to access UserDefaults using properties. However, I am stuck because I can't figure out how to make the properties dynamic, so to speak.

This is the generic idea, that API that I *want*:

```
class AppUserDefaults {
  var username = DefaultsKey<String>("username", defaultValue: "Unknown")
  var age = DefaultsKey<Int?>("age", defaultValue: nil)
}

let props = AppUserDefaults()
props.username = "bla"
print("username: \(props.username)")
```

But that (of course) doesn't work, since the type is `DefaultsKey<String>`, not `String`. So I have to add a value property to the `DefaultsKey` implementation just to add the getter and the setter, like this:

```
struct DefaultsKey<ValueType> {
  private let key: String
  private let defaultValue: ValueType

  public init(_ key: String, defaultValue: ValueType) {
    self.key = key
    self.defaultValue = defaultValue
  }

  var value: ValueType {
    get {
      let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)
      return value as? ValueType ?? defaultValue
    }
    set {
      UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
      UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
  }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
let props = AppUserDefaults()
props.username.value = "bla"
print("username: \(props.username.value)")
```

But I find that rather ugly. I also tried a subscript method, but then you're still required to add `[]` instead of `.value`:

```
struct DefaultsKey<ValueType> {
  ...
  subscript() -> ValueType {
    get {
      let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)
      return value as? ValueType ?? defaultValue
    }
    set {
      UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
      UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
  }
}

let props = AppUserDefaults()
props.username[] = "bla"
print("username: \(props.username[])")
```

Basically what I want is that I can define the getter and the setter directly on `DefaultsKey` instead of having to go through that `value` property. Is this simply not possible with Swift? Is there another way to get the behaviour that I want, where properties defined on `AppUserDefaults` are "dynamic" and go through a getter and setter, without having to define it on the property declaration inside of `AppUserDefaults`?

I hope I am using the correct terms here and made the question clear for everyone.

Comment: This will become a lot easier in Swift 4.2 when you can use a `@dynamicMemberLookup` struct.

Comment: True, but it'll lose a lot of type-certainty (not really type-safety, but you won't easily be able to restrict the keys at compile-time that way). I'm fairly certain that as written, this isn't possible; I'd say to use SwiftGen to get this (though personally, I'd accept `.value`; I use that all the time for observable things and it has the nice effect of letting you know "this isn't a trivial assignment.")

Comment: Side-note, I'd make DefaultsKey a class and the properties "let" in AppUserDefaults. As written, it's possible to swap out one `DefaultsKey` for another, which isn't what you mean. (BTW, this problem can of course be solved really easily with a custom operator, but IMO that's much worse than `.value`)

Comment: I've actually played around with a snapshot of 4.2 and `@dynamicMemberLookup` does not really make this possible either. It kinda works, but you can't have defined properties like `username` because those don't go through the `@dynamicMemberLookup` system. And you really want properties like `username` otherwise it's basically just stringly typed (accidentally using `usernamee` would not give an error).

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590993/9865234) of mine, which is using Enum keys

Comment: Hey @MichalGorzalczany, that method is what we currently use in our project, but it's those repeated getters and setters for our 30 properties we want to get rid of :)

Comment: @KevinRenskers Ok, now I fully understand your question and I am curious if someone will find the way. I'll let you know if i find sth by myself.

Comment: I've found that [literal expressible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/initialization_with_literals) may help with setter, but still have no clue about getter so this is probably wrong direction

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can think of is this:

```
struct DefaultsKey<ValueType> {
  private let key: String
  private let defaultValue: ValueType

  public init(_ key: String, defaultValue: ValueType) {
    self.key = key
    self.defaultValue = defaultValue
  }

  var value: ValueType {
    get {
      let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)
      return value as? ValueType ?? defaultValue
    }
    set {
      UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
      UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
  }
}

class AppUserDefaults {
  private var _username = DefaultsKey<String>("username", defaultValue: "Unknown")
  var username: String {
    set {
      _username.value = newValue
    },
    get {
      return _username.value
    }
  }
}

let props = AppUserDefaults()
props.username = "bla"
print("username: \(props.username)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's is an interesting workaround for now. It's not ideal since every single property needs to have these getters and setters (and I have a project with about 40 userdefault keys), but it would still be a lot less code and boilerplate then what I am currently dealing with in this project :)

Answer (score 2):

Besides all proposed variants you can also define your custom operator for assigning value to `DefaultsKey` structure.

For that your `DefaultsKey` structure should look like this:

```
struct DefaultsKey<ValueType> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: ValueType

    public init(_ key: String, defaultValue: ValueType) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }
    public private(set) var value: ValueType {
        get {
            let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)
            return value as? ValueType ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

> Explanation for `DefaultsKey` block of code:
>
> 1. `private(set) var` means that you can set value of this property only where you can access it with `private` access level (also you can write `internal(set)` or `fileprivate(set)` to be able to set it from `internal` and `fileprivate` access levels accordingly).
>
>    You will need to set `value` property later. To access this value getter is defined as `public` (by writing `public` before `private(set)`).
> 2. You do not need to use `synchronize()` method (" this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used", reference:
>      https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize).

Now it's time to define custom operator (you can name it as you want, this is just for example):

```
infix operator <<<
extension DefaultsKey {
    static func <<<(left: inout DefaultsKey<ValueType>, right: ValueType) {
        left.value = right
    }
}
```

With this operator you couldn't set value of wrong type, so it's type-safe.

To test you can use a bit modified your code:

```
class AppUserDefaults {
    var username = DefaultsKey<String>("username", defaultValue: "Unknown")
    var age = DefaultsKey<Int?>("age", defaultValue: nil)
}

let props = AppUserDefaults()
props.username <<< "bla"
props.age <<< 21
props.username <<< "Yo man"
print("username: \(props.username.value)")
print("username: \(props.age.value)")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the direction we want to go in with our project I'm afraid. Our team has no love for custom operators, me included :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [really good blog post](http://radex.io/swift/nsuserdefaults/static/) from radex.io about Statically-typed NSUserDefaults that you might find useful, if I understand what you are trying to do.

I've updated it for the latest Swift (since we now have conditional conformance) and added a default value for my implementation, which I've set out below.

```
class DefaultsKeys {}

class DefaultsKey<T>: DefaultsKeys {
    let key: String
    let defaultResult: T

    init (_ key: String, default defaultResult: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultResult = defaultResult
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {
    subscript<T>(key: DefaultsKey<T>) -> T {
        get {
            return object(forKey: key.key) as? T ?? key.defaultResult
        }
        set {
            set(newValue, forKey: key.key)
        }
    }
}

// usage - setting up the keys
extension DefaultsKeys {
    static let baseCurrencyKey = DefaultsKey<String>("Base Currency", default: Locale.current.currencyCode!)
    static let archiveFrequencyKey = DefaultsKey<Int>("Archive Frequency", default: 30)
    static let usePasswordKey = DefaultsKey<Bool>("Use Password", default: false)
}

// usage - getting and setting a value
let uDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
uDefaults[.baseCurrencyKey] = "GBP"
let currency = uDefaults[.baseCurrencyKey]
```

Comment: Yep I've seen this too, but I don't want to use it like `uDefaults[.baseCurrencyKey]`, but rather `uDefaults.baseCurrencyKey` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we are doing that in my current project. It is similar to some other answers but I think even less boiler plate. Using isFirstLaunch as an example.

```
enum UserDafaultsKeys: String {
    case isFirstLaunch
}

extension UserDefaults {

    var isFirstLaunch: Bool {
        set {
            set(!newValue, forKey: UserDafaultsKeys.isFirstLaunch.rawValue)
            synchronize()
        }
        get { return !bool(forKey: UserDafaultsKeys.isFirstLaunch.rawValue) }
    }

}
```

It is then used like this.

```
UserDefaults.standard.isFirstLaunch = true
```

It has the benefits of not needing to learn a separate object to use and is very clear where the variable is stored.

Comment: `synchronize()` is deprecated! Do not use it!  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590993/9865234) is my similar answer with extended use case.

Comment: This is exactly what we currently do in our project as well, but as we have over 30 properties, all these repeated getters and setters are getting a bit too much :)

Comment: When you say "even less boilerplate", it's those setters and getters that are the boilerplate I want to get rid of.

Comment: @KevinRenskers Ah, I understand what you are shooting for now. We have a super long list too, which is annoying but confined to one file at least. I prefer declaring them explicitly because it is clear which variables are available. This does also remove the `.value` which is nice.

Comment: @MichalGorzalczany Thanks for pointing out `synchronize()` is deprecated. Its funny they commented it is deprecated but didn't actually mark it so.

Comment: From Apple's documentation…  `synchronize()` _"… this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize